# combining javascript files

Tags: javascript

I've launched a redesign of our website and I'm using quite a bit of Javascript for the first time.

I've learned that I should be combining all my javascript and css into one file (each obviously) but while I know I can combine the css without problems but the javascript I'm not sure of.

I have to load:

jquery.min.js <-- I load the top two from ajax.googleapis.com, is that a good idea

jquery-ui.min.js

javascript for Facebook

some for google plus button

same for twitter

some for google analytics

then some inline stuff to hide divs which javascript users shouldn't see and that type of thing.

you can see it here: traditionalirishgifts.com

So can I just copy and paste the contents of all these files into one big file. Find some way to minify (haven't looked into that fully yet) it. Load this one file right at the bottom of my page before  and bingo?

Comment: You can probably get away with just naively cat-ing them together in their dependency order.

Comment: ^ Yeah for small projects that's how I do it. Just create a batch file `cat` everything and pipe it with `uglify` from NodeJS. `cat one.js two.js etc.js | uglify -o out.js`

Comment: @anthony wow that was quick! Before I'd even edited to sort out the formatting! Naively cat-ing them? dependency order?

Comment: I've no idea what this all means! Any good tutorials?

Comment: @crazysarah Concatenate the files together.  If one depends on a previous library put it after it in the mega file.  Then put it through some minifier if you care.

Comment: @crazysarah: You can also take a look at [Grunt](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt).

Comment: Don't forget there are more ways to minify than just uglifying the code; e.g. [closure compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home), find which saves you the most space/works best for you etc.

Comment: I'm still struggling with this. I'm I allowed to put all the jquery code (note I use ui as well) into the same file as everything else. Someone below said I can't put 3rd party like FB, is this true. Can some kind soul take a look at my source and tell me what is ok to include in this one file? I'll tick them right immediately! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always be able to merge all your external JavaScripts into one file. You can use a server-side compressor to cache it and serve it as one file. It does put some constraints on the files, like which file should load first etc. Also, if there is a syntax error anywhere it will crash completely.

Keep in mind that 3rd party code like code from google can't be mixed in. Usually there is some kind of authentication going on (or an API key in the URL). If you try to cache that code, it will stop working after a while. So you do need to keep those separate.

Comment: Could I impose on you to have a look at my source code and tell me which of the FB etc javascript I can't load as part of single file. But I can just copy and paste rest and that'll work? Like I've one which is just $(function() {$('.inputsPriceRange').hide();$('#displaypricerange').show();}); So in my eyes this is just a function nothing calls it?

Comment: No 3rd party code whatsoever really. If they ever decide to change their API slightly you might still by trying the old version and it will break in unexpected ways.

Comment: does that include the two jquery files?

Answer (score 2):

I'd use this tool: http://jscompress.com/

> JSCompress.com is an online javascript compressor that allows you to
>   compress and minify your javascript files. Compressed javascript files
>   are ideal for production environments since they typically reduce the
>   size of the file by 30-90%. Most of the filesize reduction is achieved
>   by removing comments and extra whitespace characters that are not
>   needed by web browsers or visitors.